# How to non-greedy search from the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm tying to search from the beginning of the string but I can't figure how.

If the string was `>plaplapla>plaplapla(321)`, I want to get the text with regex `/>.+?\(\d.\)/` starting from the last occurrence of the first char `>`.

For example, if the text was `>fir5t W0rd$ > $ec0nd here(2) >third here()`, the text that I want to extract is `> $ec0nd here(2)`.

I tried to use the regix `/>.+?\(\d.\)/` but it gives me `>fir5t W0rd$ > $ec0nd here(2)` instead of `> $ec0nd here(2)`.

How can I modify the regix so it starts from the last position of the occurrence of the '>' character?

Comment: That happens because the string is processed from left to right and once the first `<` is matched, the `.*?` (though lazy) matches up to the first `(`, digits, `)`. So it can match across `<` symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your string seems to be `>` delimited use a `[^>]` negated character class instead of a `.*?` lazy dot pattern:

```
/>[^>]+\(\d+\)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u3rEVB/2). Note that `/>[^>]+?\(\d+\)/` will work similarly, but will match up to the first `(<DIGITS>)` substring after the `>`. See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/SsrTPF/1) and [the one above](https://regex101.com/r/SsrTPF/2).

**Details**

- `>` - a literal `>`
- `[^>]+` - 1 or more chars other than `>` as many as possible
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `\d+` -  one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/>[^>]+?\(\d\)/
```

This way your regex will not capture the character `>` so you will get the second instance of it.

[Regex 101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/BSw8xt/1)